# number_format и float

Tags: php

У меня есть 2 числа
A)0.00000023
B) 123.33000000
При выводе числа A я получаю 2.3E-7, но мне нужно вывести его полностью, я использую функцию

```
number_format(0.00000023, 8, '.', '');
```

Но в таком случае число В, выводиться полностью со всеми нулями 123.33000000.

Мне нужно чтобы при выводе число А, выводилось полностью в формате `0.00000023`, а число В, без лишних нулей `123.33`, как это сделать? Это числа из одного цикла, поэтому разные функции для них написать не получиться

Comment: В этом случае можно использовать sprintf("%7.8f", $floatNumber);

Answer (score 0):

Решил проверкой, `echo ($num > 0.00010000) ? round($num ,2) : $num`

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $num), '0');
```